# How to create a CRS (projection) for accurate celestial mapping in QGIS/ArcGIS?

Tags: coordinates, gis, arcgis, projection, qgis

I'm currently creating a celestial map using QGIS/ArcMap. As you know, unlike earth, the canopy is a perfect sphere where the lengths of **Major axis = Minor axis**. But in the softwares I failed to find out a CRS that's suitable for the canopy. **NOTED that the projection should allow me to create large polygon features that covers the north/south poles and/or crosses meridian lines** without malshaping by itself. But after several weeks (!) of searching through the net and reading GIS books, I still at nowhere.

Imagine to create an accurate ecliptic line for J0.0.

Anyway, program using code isn't available to me, so a PRJ file or clues of writing one would be greatly appreciated.

Have tried to modify the default North Pole Lambert projection with custom GCS & datum. But after import, I can no more create features that across north pole - they'll become triangles.

Comment: I think you are overthinking. You will not have a CRS (how do you define the distance of one degree?) Just use any existing projection which transform degrees into Cartesian (screen pixels) with distortion trade-off as you prefer. And by defining J0.0 you define where is 0 degree (and note the different angle convention). (and use one existing CRS with a sphere as basis).